# Find the relation between $x$ and $y$ for each of the following parts:-

Tags: trigonometry

Find the relation between $x$ and $y$ for each of the following parts:-

My attempt is as follows:-

**I$^{st}$ part**: If $x=\cos\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}\right)\right)$

$$x=\cos\left(\cos^{-1}\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}\right)$$
$$x=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}$$

But actual answer is $x^2+y^2=1$

**I don't understand why they are not taking the mod around $x$.**

I have taken mod because range of $\sin^{-1}$ is $\left[-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and $\cos$ is positive in I$^{st}$ and IV$^{th}$ quadrant.

**II$^{nd}$ part**: If $x=\tan\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}\right)\right)$

$$x=\tan\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{|x|}\right)\right)$$
$$x=\frac{y}{|x|}$$

But actual answer is $y=x^2$

**I don't understand why they are not taking the mod around $x$.**

I have taken mod because range of $\sin^{-1}$ is $\left[-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and $\tan$ will be positive if $\sin^{-1}$ is $\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and non-positive otherwise, so everything should depend on the sign of $y$

I think I am doing the right thing, but getting doubt as my answer is not matching.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by *taking the mod around $x$*?  Anyway, 
\begin{align}
x=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}&\implies x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=|x|\\
&\implies\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac{|x|}{x}\\
&\implies\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1
\end{align}

These two equations are representative of the same relationship between the variables.  The same can be said about your other question.

Comment: how can you say $\dfrac{|x|}{x}$ is $1$?, for that you must know what is the sign of $x$

Comment: The results of both absolute value and square root are non-negative.

Comment: I have given the reason in the post why there should be $|x|$ instead of just x.

Comment: ok fair enough, what about second part?

Comment: by taking the mod around $x$ means surrounding $x$ with mod symbol :)

Answer (score 0):

Since $\arcsin$ range $\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ we can take

$$\cos \theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta}$$

then, assuming $x\ge 0$

$$x=\cos\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}\right)\right)=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}\right)^2}=\frac x {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

and for the second one

$$x=\tan\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}\right)\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}\right)\right)}{\cos\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}\right)\right)}=\frac{\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}}{\frac x {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}=\frac y x$$

Comment: yeah just tell me if $x$ is $-3$ and y is $-4$, in that case $\sin^{-1}\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ would be negative because range of $\sin^{-1}$ is $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, and this would give the angle in fourth quadrant and tan is negative over there and according to your answer $\tan\theta=\dfrac{4}{3}$

Comment: @user3290550 The first result I've given is valid for $x\ge 0$, otherwise you are right we need to take the absolute value.